# Swagger generated Java Client has no overloaded calls, even though the query parameter is marked as optional

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'm introducing an **optional**  "query parameter" (**with default value**) for one of my API endpoint ( i.e. /foo2) but hoping that existing API consumers don't have to make any changes in their application when they regenerate the java client stub from the new swagger file.

I was expecting that the generated java client will offer overloaded methods, to operate with and without a method parameter, so that my existing API consumers can work without any changes to their call. At the same time, they can switch to its more generic offering.

```
public void foo2Get() throws ApiException {
public void foo2Get(String type) throws ApiException {
```

**But it generates ONLY the latter**. I don't see the former.

At the same time, generated python client from same swagger throws a var arg and this way it more flexible and hence old and new offerings will work without any issues.

```
def foo2_get(self, **kwargs):
```

(swagger sample used: attached)

** Description**
Is there a way to overcome this limitation with java code generator.

**swagger-generator version**

swagger 2.0

**Swagger declaration file content or url**

```
      swagger: '2.0'
      info:
        title: identity
        version: Unknown
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        typeParam:
          name: type
          in: query
          required: false
          allowEmptyValue: true
          default: basic
          type: string
          enum: 
           - basic
           - advanced

      paths:
        /foo2:
          get:
            consumes:
              - application/json
            parameters:
               - "$ref": "#/parameters/typeParam"
            responses:
              '200':
                description: OK
```